# How to specify an optionLabelTemplate Kendo UI DropDownList with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am having difficulty using the optionLabelTemplate on a dropdownlist through an angular options binding in KendoUI.

Version: Kendo UI v2015.1.430

Markup:

```
         <select kendo-drop-down-list
                k-options="DropDownOptionsTest"></select>
```

Script:

```
    var TestData = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([{value:"one", id:1}, {value:"two", id:2}]);
    $scope.DropDownOptionsTest = {
        dataSource: TestData,
        optionLabelTemplate: '<span>SelectText...</span>',
        dataTextField: "value",
        dataValueField: "id"
    };
```

Result:
No options label appears, first option is automatically selected.

Can someone please explain to me why that doesn't work and how I can make it work?

Comment: Hard to say, but you have a few events to check it out: `schema.parse` and `dataBound` to check how the data is being received by the widget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do is display a default text ("SelectText...") when the drop down list is first rendered and there is no selection. The way to do this is with the `optionLabel` attribute. You can also use the `optionLabelTemplate` you are already using in order to customise the markup of the option label **but only if an option label already exists**.
Therefore, while this doesn't work:

```
$scope.DropDownOptionsTest = {
        dataSource: TestData,
        optionLabelTemplate: '<span>Select Text...</span>',
        dataTextField: "value",
        dataValueField: "id"
    };
```

This does:

```
$scope.DropDownOptionsTest = {
        dataSource: TestData,
        optionLabel: 'Select Text...'
        optionLabelTemplate: '<span>Select Text...</span>',
        dataTextField: "value",
        dataValueField: "id"
    };
```

Please note that in this case the optionLabel will be disregarded, since the optionLabelTemplate determines what will be rendered by the drop down list, it still needs to be there nevertheless.
Finally, you can also use the value of your optionLabel in your optionLabelTemplate with something like this (although I can't think of any use case where you might need to do something this complex):

```
$scope.DropDownOptionsTest = {
        dataSource: $scope.testData,
        optionLabel: 'Select one...',
        optionLabelTemplate: function(optionLabel){return '<span>' + optionLabel + '</span>'},
        dataTextField: "value",
        dataValueField: "id"
    };
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you! I could not find this very useful bit of info in the docs. So hopefully this will help other people too. Further info for anyone who happens to read this and is doing the same as me: I set the tempate as '<label translate="global_select_text"></label>' and with the angular-translate module this works beautifully.

Comment: Thanks Christina. Goodness knows why they failed to document this in the API docs.

Comment: I had almost given up after about an hour of playing around with the optionLabel and optionLabel template. Thank goodness I found this post. It is not logical at all that you need the optionLabl to use the optionLabelTemplate just so it can get ignored. No sane person would try this in their attempt to get a optionLabelTemplate working. Thank you!!!